# Get everything back on OSX

Tags: macos, kernel, kernel-extensions

I really need your help.
I've tried to improve my graphic card with the help of this Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5EKzHq4pAk&t=117s

> cd /S*/L*/Ext*/AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB.kext/C*/M*
>   
> sudo cp AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB.backup
>   sudo perl -pi -e 's|\xC7\x45\xBC\x00\x00\x00\x20|\xc7\x45\xBC\x00\x00\x00\x40|g' AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB
>   sudo touch /S*/L*/Extensions

But after this, my mac doesn't see my HD3000
How can i get everything back using kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Boot into [recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) and reinstall OS X on top of your existing installation. This shouldn't delete your data (but you have that on backups anyway, right?), just repair your OS.

If you also downloaded some random software from obscure russian servers as suggested in the link you posted and gave that software admin access to your computer, you might want to wipe your system and do a fresh install. It could easily have installed malware.

And maybe don't patch your kernel with instructions from YouTube without knowing exactly what you're doing in future? (And questions like this go on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ as it's not programming-related but just general how to use a Mac stuff.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i cant enter recovery mode, because my internal graphics card was crashed after this manipulation from YouTube

Comment: Have you tried resetting the PRAM/NVRAM? If it's a firmware problem, that should fix it. If you still can't enter the boot menu or recovery mode then, your hardware is defective, and you'll need to get it fixed. Recovery mode doesn't use the installed OSX kernel and drivers, so if it was purely a software problem, you could get into recovery mode.

Comment: Yes, i've reset NVRAM. But for sure, after all this YouTube manipulation, it doesn't show me even gray screen, to see gray screen of load, i need to wait about 20 minutes to heat it, and only then i can see how it loads.

Comment: Sounds like you've really messed up the device then, you'll probably have to get it professionally serviced.